# How to check if a number divides a very large number using modulo

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would I determine if 13 divides 12<sup>12</sup> -1

I know the question's asking if 12<sup>12</sup> is congruent to 1 (mod 13), but how would I go about solving this without a calculator?

Comment: Have you heard of Fermat's Little Theorem? Moreover using the fact that 12 is congruent to -1 modulo 13 helps a lot

Comment: MSE is for mathematicians for all abilities

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$12\equiv -1\mod 13$$ so $$12^{12}\equiv (-1)^{12}\mod 13$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: (*without the use of congruences*)

$$12^{12}-1=(13-1)^{12}-1$$

When expanding the parentheses, how many terms are not divisible by $13$?